# javascript unable to get previousSibling Class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the div class so i can add the functionality to it

Here is my JS Code

`idName` is giving me name as Tuesday

```
console.log(document.querySelector("#w1_"+idName.split('_')[1]).previousSibling);
            document.querySelector("#w1_"+idName.split('_')[1]).previousSibling.classList.remove('specialCheckbox2');
            document.querySelector("#w1_"+idName.split('_')[1]).previousSibling.classList.add('specialCheckbox3');
            document.querySelector("#w1_"+idName.split('_')[1]).disabled = true;
```

and here my html

```
<div class="specialCheckbox2"><input class="checktip" type="checkbox" value="1" name="w1_Tuesday" id="w1_Tuesday"><label for="w1_Tuesday"></label></div>
```

Comment: Well `"Tuesday".split('_')[1]` is `undefined`…

Comment: no, Tuesday is the rendered value after the idName as its value is r1_Tuesday so i am just extracting Tuesday

Comment: @Geshode I've rolled back your edit since whitespace is actually relevant in a question asking about sibling nodes.

Comment: `parentNode` seems more appropriate than `previousSibling`

Comment: @Bergi The div, which OP wants to get to, since it has the class, which OP removes, is the parent and not a sibling. So, I thought, I change it to make it easier to see that relationship of the elements. But okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element with the `w1_Tuesday` id is the first sibling. There isn't one before it, so `previousSibling` will return null.

It looks to me like you want to get the surrounding div with the `specialCheckbox2` class. That can be gotten with [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) like this:

```
const parent = document.querySelector("#w1_"+idName.split('_')[1]).parentElement;
parent.classList.remove('specialCheckbox2');
parent.classList.add('specialCheckbox3');
```

Or [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) is also an option:

```
const parent = document.querySelector("#w1_"+idName.split('_')[1]).parentNode;
parent.classList.remove('specialCheckbox2');
parent.classList.add('specialCheckbox3');
```